# Verify User Token in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, ionic3, jwt

I have an ionic 3 application that is using laravel as backend . For auth I am using JWT and everything is working fine  from registration , login and posting data within the app.

Problem starts when the user closes the mobile app and opens it again, I want the app to auto login the user using the saved token in storage.

The code below is for checking if the user has a token in storage, if there is then the token needs to be sent to laravel backend for verification.

```
verifyToken() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.storage.get("token").then((value) => {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append("Accept", "application/json");
        headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + value);
        this.http.post(ApiUrl + "/verifyToken", { headers: headers }).subscribe(
          (res) => {
            let data = res.json();
            console.log("Valid token results:", data);
            resolve(data);
          },
          (error: any) => {
            console.log("Token was invalid", error);
            reject(JSON.parse(error._body));
          }
        );
      });
    });
  }
```

On Laravel backend I have this code for verification

```
 public function verifyToken()
    {
        try {

            if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
                return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => 'User not found.',$e->getStatusCode()], 404);
            }

        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

            return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => 'Login Token expired.',$e->getStatusCode()], 401);

        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

            return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => 'Login Token invalid.',$e->getStatusCode()], 401);

        } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

            return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => 'Login Token not supplied.',$e->getStatusCode()], 401);

        }

        // the token is valid and we have found the user
        return response()->json(['success' => true, 'message' => 'Token is valid.'], 200);

    }
```

When I test this via postman and provide valid user token, I get status 200 but when I do the same on the mobile app I get an error 500

```
"message": "The token could not be parsed from the request",
"exception": "Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException",.
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it to work, I had to pass the token in body when sending my post in ionic.